# Disable use of proxy

Tags: proxy

[Bionic]
For some reason all my network apps insist on using a proxy even for internal hosts.
http(s)_proxy, HTTP(S)_PROXY aren't set.

I don't understand where these proxy settings come from but i want to get rid of them.
Any ideas on how to do this ? (i also made sure that the option "no proxy" was selected in the network settings)

Where could those settings be hiding ?

Comment: What makes you think that the system is using proxy ?

Comment: Hello  Cubiculo Obscuro, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected? If so, what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: If it is a corporate network then you don't really control the routing and everything can be routed to a proxy behind your back.